# Exchange two 'onclicks' in ie

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want to change the onclicks of two elements. In Firefox this code does what it should:

```
var tmpButton = button1.onclick;
button1.setAttribute('onclick', button2.onclick);
button2.setAttribute('onclick', tmpButton);
```

But how can i realize this code in IE ?

Comment: Have you tried using simply `button1.onclick = button2.onclick`? The setAttribute method is not 100% cross-browser safe.

Comment: Unfortunately not! I tried it but it failed!

Comment: It works. I've just tested in IE6, IE7 and IE8. If it breaks for you then your bug is most likely somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work in both browsers:

```
var tmpButton = button1.onclick;
button1.onclick = button2.onclick;
button2.onclick = tmpButton;
```

The setAttribute method is not 100% cross-platform safe. [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) says IE implementation of `setAttribute` is incomplete:

> IE5-7 doesn't set styles and removes events when you try to set them.

*Note: working example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/slebetman/RHHzc/*

Comment: I tried it but if failed after this the exchanged elements got no onclick-attributes so the onclick-event is not available...

Comment: Ok and how does it look if i want to change the 'onclicks' when pressing one of the buttons and not a third one?

Comment: It looks the same except that obviously you'd implement the toggle code in the event handler of one of the two buttons instead of a third button. Is there something else about your problem that's not obvious? Because you're only posting the reassignment code so I'm assuming you know how/where to implement it. Your question implies that that may not be the case.

Comment: As I've said in my comment to your original question. It is very likely your problem is somewhere else because the reassignment code works. That being the case, you need to figure out where it is and tell us about it otherwise we can't help because we have no idea what the problem really is.